# How can I mute warnings and errors in SVN?

Tags: linux, svn, warnings, suppress-warnings

When I run command like `svn ls *.py`, it throws warnings since some of `*.py` files in the working dir are not under track.

I wonder if I can somehow **mute** warnings and errors from an svn command? I know it's not recommended to mute warnings/errors, I'm aware of the risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at `svn help ls`, there's a parameter for that case: `--search ARG` which supports glob syntax.

Running `svn ls --search "*.py"` will print information only on those Python files that are under version control. The quotes around the glob pattern are needed to prevent the shell from expanding the '*'.

In case you really want to mute warnings and errors anyway, you can just redirect them as you can do with any process in the shell. The normal output goes to *stdout* while errors and warnings go to *stderr* so you can just do `svn ls *.py 2> /dev/null`. Note that this will swallow up *all* errors, even those unrelated to unversioned files.

In a simple example, both commands give identical output:

```
> ls
foo.py
bar.py
> svn st
?       bar.py
> svn ls --search "*.py"
foo.py
> svn ls *.py 2> /dev/null
foo.py
```